# C# SignalR problemas de conexion

Tags: signalr

A ver si alguien puede echarme un cable.

estoy empezando pruebas de conexión a través de SignalR ,por una parte tengo una pequeña aplicación de consola en código c# que es la que hace de servidor y por otra parte una en Windows Forms también en c# que es el cliente.

El servidor se inicia con el siguiente código:

```
string url = "http://localhost:8080";
using (WebApp.Start(url))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

por parte del cliente se inicia:

```
string url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
var _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
connection.Start().Wait();
```

Todo esto funciona bien si los 2 programas están en el mismo pc, pero si el programa del servidor lo pongo en otro pc de la red local. ya no me funciona, el url del terminal lo cambio por `http://192.168.1.14:8080/signalr`, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent,  Headers: { Connection: close Date:
>   Tue, 13 Nov 2018 10:38:04 GMT Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>   Content-Length: 334  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii }

He probado a desactivar cortafuegos antivirus, etc y nada, llevo ya varios días con esto y no puedo continuar, espero alguien tenga alguna solución.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes que habilitar el puerto en el cortafuegos de windows, o desactivarlo, para que las conexiones entre distintos pc te funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno pues me respondo a mi mismo por si ha alguien le ocurre lo mismo.
En la url hay que poner lo siguiente:
string url = "http://*:8080";

Comment: Que raro, esa manera tambien te funciona en local, como la anterior?

Comment: Esta manera si me funciona, la otra no

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate de:

1. Tener una regla en el cortafuegos *(hacia el puerto en cuestión)* o tenerlo desactivado.
2. Asegurarte de estar ejecutando tu aplicación con permisos de Administrador.

Comment: Si, eso ya lo he probado, los cortafuegos están desactivados en los 2 equipos y se ejecutan con permisos de administrador